# Async method sending response back to Main

Tags: c#, .net, async-await, task, task-parallel-library

I have implemented a soap client using a Async method. I want this method to return a string value that I get from the API server to my main Thread or to another method (whichever method is calling). How do I do this:

**MAIN THREAD**

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
 {

  TEXT().GetAwaiter().OnCompleted(() => { Console.WriteLine("finished"); });
  Console.ReadKey();

 // if I do it like this
 //  var test =  TEXT().GetAwaiter().OnCompleted(() => { Console.WriteLine("finished"); });
 // it gives me error: Cannot assign void to an implicitly-typed local variable
  }
```

**ASYNC METHOD**

```
 public static async Task<string> TEXT()
 {
     Uri uri = new Uri("http://myaddress");
     HttpClient hc = new HttpClient();
     hc.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("SOAPAction", "Some Action");
     var xmlStr = "SoapContent"; //not displayed here for simplicity
   var content = new StringContent(xmlStr, Encoding.UTF8, "text/xml");


  using (HttpResponseMessage response = await hc.PostAsync(uri, content))
  {
   var soapResponse = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
   string value = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
   return value; //how do I get this back to the main thread or any other method
  }
 }
```

Comment: Version? If on C#7 you should use [async main](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mazhou/2017/05/30/c-7-series-part-2-async-main/).

Comment: .Net 4.5, VS 2013

Comment: Do you mean `string result = TEXT().Result;`? Just in case - you cannot do this in most types of applications (WinForms, WPF, ASP.NET etc.), but since you say it is a console app - it is fine.

Comment: I need the `value` returned to the main thread like `var test =  TEXT().GetAwaiter().OnCompleted(() => { Console.WriteLine("finished");`, but I'm getting an error: `Cannot assign void to an implicitly-typed local variable`

Comment: @user726720 So, does `var test = TEXT().Result; Console.WriteLine(test);` work for you?

Comment: @YeldarKurmangaliyev: Yes perfect, that works. So simple, I'm just dumb. Sorry. Post it as answer please, also in your answer mention for other methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a pre-C# 7.0 console application it can be achieved as simple as this:

```
public static void Main()
{
    string result = TEXT().Result;
    Console.WriteLine(result);
}
```

In this case `TEXT` can be considered a usual method, which returns `Task<string>`, so its result is available in `Result` property. You don't need to mess with awaiter, results etc.

At the same time, you cannot do this in most types of applications (WinForms, WPF, ASP.NET etc.) and in this case you will have to use async/await across all your application:

```
public async Task SomeMethod()
{
    string result = await TEXT();
    // ... do something with result
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the eyeopener here. Actually I'm testing this on ConsoleApp now but later want to move it to WinForms. Is it possible for you to show a WinForms example as well. You can make it brief. Will be grateful. Thanks.

Comment: @user726720 There is nothing to show in general :) Both in WinForms and WPF you will have synchronous `Main` which will run your app, but then inside your application you will need to use `await TEXT()` (see updated answer).

Comment: Understood. Thanks. Accepted for simplicity.

Comment: In WinForms, you want to make your eventhandlers  `async void`.

Answer (score 1):

If you plan to do a lot of async in a console application, I recommend using this sort of MainAsync pattern:

```
static public void Main(string[] args) //Entry point
{
    MainAsync(args).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
}

static public Task MainAsync(string[] args) //Async entry point
{
    await TEXT();
    Console.WriteLine("finished"); 
}
```

If you upgrade to C# 7.1 or later, you can then remove the `Main` method and use [async main](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mazhou/2017/05/30/c-7-series-part-2-async-main/).

Or if you ever migrate this code to an ASP.NET or WinForms application, you can ignore `Main` and migrate the code in `MainAsync` (otherwise you will run afoul of the synchronization model and get deadlocked).

Answer (score 0):

In C# 7.0+, you can use `async Task Main`

```
static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    var result =  TEXT().ConfigureAwait(false)
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

for older versions of C#

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
  try
  {
    TEST().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    WriteLine($"There was an exception: {ex.ToString()}");
  }
}
```

Comment: How about for `.Net 4.5, VS 2013 `

Comment: Why not to return inside `using` statement? It looks good for me :)

Comment: Yes, good point would like to know, Simonare can you explain please.

Comment: @YeldarKurmangaliyev, I removed that part. I checked it and return does not have any side effects for Disposal. thank you